# Topological quotient of Integers by odd numbers

Tags: general-topology

From what I can tell, there are no open sets in the quotient topology of a space $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\; the \; odd \;  numbers}$ when the only open set is 1 in the pre image  (or any proper subset of odd integers) because not all of the pre images are open. Is that true or false though thanks...….

Comment: This is not the correct notation for quotient spaces.

Comment: I thought you can pick your own topologies on sets so that for one example 1 is open in z and the rest are closed....

Comment: No, the topology is uniquely determined by the topolgoy on the original space and the quotient map. No choice is involved.

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is the set of odd integers, and we consider an equivalence relation on $\Bbb Z$ which has classes $T$, and $\{n\}$ (for even $n$) and $q: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z{/}T$ is the natural quotient map, what does the quotient topology look like?

$q^{-1}[\{T\}] = T$ is open in $\Bbb Z$ (which is discrete, so all subsets are open) and so $\{T\}$ is open in $\Bbb Z{/}T$.

The same holds for the other singletons $\{\{n\}\}$ in $\Bbb Z{/}T$ and so the quotient is discrete.

In general, any quotient of a discrete space is discrete too.

Comment: A quotient topolgy has an open set iff each preimage of the supposedly open set is open tho right?? thanks that is my last question.

Comment: @DanielImber Yes, $O \subseteq \Bbb Z{/}T$ is open iff $q^{-1}[O]$ is open. But the latter is always the case when the left hand space is discrete.